# Get a hash of a table in duckdb

Tags: r, duckdb

I have duckdb database with large tables (~100mln rows) where I want to see if some values have changed in a specific table. I do not need to see which rows have changed, just if any have changed at all.

One way to achieve this is to use a hash of the table. In its simplest form that could be a row-count but ideally it would take the values of the table into account as well, which a proper hash algorithm like md5 or similar would do.

A solution would be to get the data into R and then compute a hash, but this would mean pulling all data into R, which might take a long while.

Is there an efficient way to do this? Ie can I `CALL`/`PRAGMA` duckdb to get a hash/size/id of a table?

## MWE

A minimum working example using R would be this.

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb())
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars)

rlang::hash(DBI::dbReadTable(con, "mtcars")) # transfers all data into R and computes the hash in R
#> [1] "24bc99234ecb908438a9e0bfb4313c73"

# update some values in the table
DBI::dbExecute(con, "UPDATE mtcars SET disp = 123 WHERE mpg = 10.4")
# compute the hash again to see if it has changed
rlang::hash(DBI::dbReadTable(con, "mtcars"))
#> [1] "64802a862b2419d9d098bbd43b614aab"
```

Comment: I have actually just asked pretty much the same question in DuckDB's Discord Server, because, afaik, there is no function to do that. But let's see if someone throw us some light on that. Meanwhile, not sure if it works for you, but the workaround I am using is to keep one table per duckdb file and hash the whole file -e.g. rlang::hash_file("foo.db")-

Comment: Note there is a `hash()` function in duckdb, but this seems to work only with values or sets but not tables/queries: https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/functions/utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not need to see which rows have changed, just if any have changed at all.

I was led to this question looking for a row hashing function.

Appears you can cast a row to TEXT, which returns its JSON string representation, then use the HASH(), MD5() functions to emulate a row hash function:

`SELECT tbl::TEXT, HASH(tbl::TEXT), MD5(tbl::TEXT) FROM tbl;`

```
D create table tbl as (select 1 as a, 2 as b, 3 as c);
D select tbl::text, hash(tbl::text), md5(tbl::text) from tbl;
┌──────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────┐
│   CAST(tbl AS VARCHAR)   │ hash(CAST(tbl AS VARCHAR)) │    md5(CAST(tbl AS VARCHAR))     │
│         varchar          │           uint64           │             varchar              │
├──────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│ {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3} │        6764392534128998287 │ e31681d6e7ab078c9679fcd4f50136eb │
└──────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────┘
```

The text of rows can be aggregated and hashed to a single value, unknown if there are limits to how many rows (string size) this can support:

`SELECT md5(string_agg(tbl::text, '')) FROM tbl;`