# DuckDb Hash a Record

Tags: python, duckdb

I have a use case where I want to check for conflicts for slowly changing dimensions.  In theory, I should be able to do this by hashing a record of the original table and compare it to a hash of the new record coming in if the ID's match.

In SQL I can do this with a binary checksum and just provide a list of column names.

In DuckDb it appears the hash functions are all single column.  Is there a convenient way to do this that isn't concatenating all of the columns together or comparing each column individually?

Alternatively, I could hash the rows outside of DuckDb in Python, but as the data is stored in Parquet, it is very convenient if I can just keep this all in DuckDb.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77214715/get-a-hash-of-a-table-in-duckdb/77302869#77302869

Answer (score 0):

There probably is a simpler way to do it, but I think this will work:

```
create or replace table data(a int, b varchar, c float);

insert into data 
values (1,'a', 0.3),(1,'a', 0.3),(2,'c',0.4), (1,'a', 0.55);

select a,b,c, struct_pack(a := a, b := b, c := c) as my_struct, md5(my_struct) my_md5
from data
order by a,b,c;
```